# Meaning of a passage in "Night on Highway 128" by Cary Mullis

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

From *[Night on Highway 128](https://www.europeanpharmaceuticalreview.com/article/1073/night-on-highway-128/)* by Cary Mullis:

> I was driving up a long and winding road between Cloverdale and Booneville in Mendocino County, heading for my weekend cabin. My girlfriend was asleep and I was functionally sober (or the road would have proven my undoing) but it was late at night and I was feeling weird. **Strange things had happened to me on 128 before. Furtive old men in… what was that? A grey robe. In that field. I didn’t see anything.** Or lost time: the distinct feeling, shared by my former wife, pulling into Booneville and recalling that we had just left Cloverdale, now thirty five miles to the southeast.

I struggle to understand the meaning of this passage. Does it mean the author had prevously seen "a furtive old man (or men)" wearing grey robe/robes when riding along this road, but on this account he didn't see anything of such sort?

Comment: There is no reason to think that the words used in this passage mean anything different from what they ordinarily mean. There is also nothing about the grammatical structures used here that needs an explanation. What the question calls for is interpretation of this text as a work of literature.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for literary analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a writing style question. The entire piece is a description of the author's thought process regarding a scientific problem. The paragraph you cite begins a narrative in which he ascribes a mystic quality to Highway 128. My interpretation is that, as the author begins slipping into deep thought late at night during his drive, he has a minor hallucination in that specific moment, while he is driving, that snaps him out of his thought for a moment.

I'm not sure what the context of your question is, but-- in terms of style-- the car ride adds an element of narrative interest to the story, but provides no significant meaning to the actual article itself. In that sense, if there are other interpretations, that wouldn't change the article's meaning in any way.